# How to prevent runtime PHP code changes to be replaced when a web dyno restarts?

Tags: php, heroku, runtime

The installation process of my php website edits few php files and does additional setup, it downloads cites... (I don't know all the details I bought it). It works ok on the current server.

I am trying to deploy it on Heroku, everything goes well until the web dynos restarts. All the configuration done during the install process is erased by the last push version of the code.

As a result, each time my web dyno restarts I need to go through the same install process.

I tried the slug method to download the project and push it back to git with the changes done by the install process but the slug contains the initial php source code.

Thank you for your help

Comment: "The installation process of my php website edits few php files"—why? This sounds like an antipattern, and won't work on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, you're right, unfortunately, I have to deal with it, the only solution I can see is to retrieve the files from Heroku after the install and have them pushed back into git. Heroku is not very friendly, even retrieving the files is a pain. The files I am seeing through the console are the initial files

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* you think you need to modify files on the server. Again, it's an antipattern. "Heroku is not very friendly, even retrieving the files is a pain"—Heroku's design is very thoughtful, and it's intended to make it easy to follow good practices and hard or even impossible to use bad ones. Please see https://12factor.net/